# How to use High Replication Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Okay, I have watched the [video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/more-9s-please-under-the-covers-of-the-high-replication-datastore.html) and read the articles in the App Engine documentation (including [Using the High Replication Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html)). However I am still completely confused on the practical usage of it. I understand the benefits (from the video) and they sound great. But what I am lacking is a few practical examples. There are plenty of master/slave examples on the web, but very little illustrating (with proper documentation) the high replication datastore. The guestbook code example used in the [Using the High Replication Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html) article illustrates the ancestor key by adding a new functionality that the previous guestbook code example does not have (seems you can change guestbook). This just adds to the confusion.

I often use [djangoforms](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) on GAE and I was wondering if someone can help me translate all these queries into high replication datastore compatible queries (let's forget for a moment the discussion that not all queries necessarily need to be high replication datastore compatible queries and focus on the example itself).

**UPDATE: with high replication datastore compatible queries I refer to queries that always return the latest data and not potential stale data. Using entity groups seems to be the way to go here but as mentioned before, I don't have many practical code examples of how to do this, so that is what I am looking for!**

So [the queries in this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) are:

The main recurring query in this article is:

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY name")
```

which we will translate to:

```
query = Item.all().order('name')  // datastore request
```

validating the form happens like:

```
data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST)
if data.is_valid():
    # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
    entity = data.save(commit=False)
    entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
    entity.put()  // datastore request
```

and getting the latest entry from the datastore for populating a form happens like:

```
id = int(self.request.get('id'))
item = Item.get(db.Key.from_path('Item', id))  // datastore request
data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST, instance=item)
```

So what do I/we need to do to make all these datastore requests compatible with the high replication datastore?

One last thing that is also not clear to me. Using ancestor keys, does this have any impact on the model in datastore. For example, in the guestbook code example they use:

```
def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')
```

However 'Guestbook' does not exist [in the model](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/guestbook_highrep/guestbook.py#34), so how can you use 'db.Key.from_path' on this and why would this work? Does this change how data is stored in the datastore which I need to keep into account when retrieving the data (e.g. does it add another field I should exclude from showing when using djangoforms)?

Like I said before, this is confusing me a lot and your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a magic recipe to make the HR datastore act like the M/S one. There isn't one - you simply have to consider what the consequences of stale data are on each of your queries, and restructure if that's a problem.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions. I am not trying to get a magic recipe for the HR to act like the M/S, although I think I understand why you may think that. What I am trying to get is code snippets, using these examples, to actually be able to code HR compatible requests (note: with no stale data). For the last few years I worked with M/S and now I want to work with HR but I have no idea how. The documentation on the GAE website is very minimal with actual code examples. I choose the djangoforms example because I use this a lot and can focus on the new code.

Comment: "Note: with no stale data" - is pretty much asking for a way to turn HR into MS. You don't need to change your queries to work with HR - you simply need to accept that it's eventually consistent, and rework things where necessary to take that into account.

Comment: Like I said, I can see how you may think that. However, I am trying to get examples here where you use entity groups and ancestor keys as this is too confusing. You mentioned that I don't need to rewrite my queries and that there is no way of not having any stale data? Please keep in mind that I understand that not every query needs to be latest data (in fact I explicitly mentioned to leave that discussion out for now) and that you want to work with mostly stale data. Unfortunately your answer does not give me code examples on how to rewrite my queries to use entity groups and ancestor keys.

Comment: Just to add to the example: Imagine I use djangoforms to update a row or enter a new row in the HR datastore using the normal queries (as mentioned above in my question). After this transaction I redirect the user to a handler where I query this data and show it to the user. According to you I can't do this and I don't need to rewrite my code? I thought the whole idea of entity groups and ancestor keys was to bridge this gap, and allow you to get the latest data. Please elaborate on why you say I can't do this by changing the query? I really appreciate it as I am trying to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think you need to change your queries at all. The documentation that you link to clearly states:

> The back end changes, but the datastore API does not change at all. You'll use the same programming interfaces no matter which datastore you're using.

The point of that page is just to say that queries may be out of sync if you don't use entity groups. Your final code snippet is just an example of that - the string 'Guestbook' is exactly an ancestor key. I don't understand why you think it needs to exist in the model. Once again, this is unchanged from the non-HR datastore - it has always been the case that keys are built up from paths, which can consist of arbitrary strings. You probably need to reread the documentation on [entity groups and keys](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths).

Comment: You just beat me to it. Though, "Guestbook" isn't an ancestor key. It's the [kind of the key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path).

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to try answer my questions. I really appreciate it. The only thing is, that I want to know how to rewrite these queries I mentioned above to work nicely with the high replication datastore (sorry for not being clear enough, but this means for me having access to the latest data and not stale data). I reread the document you linked actually already over 5 times and still am not getting it how to rewrite my code. I think I understand (part of) the theory behind why to use it and also stale data vs latest data but not how to accomplish this with actual code.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions. Unfortunately this does not seem to be true if you want the latest data. Sometimes you need the latest data (especially after updating something) and then you want use/show this to the user. In these cases the normal queries (as currently documented and listed above in my question) as not sufficient enough with HR datastore.

Answer (score 1):

The changes to use the HRD are not in how queries are made, but in what guarantees are made about what data you get back. The example you give:

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY name")
```

will work in the HRD as well. The catch (basically) is that this kind of query (using either this syntax, or the Item.all() form) can return objects slightly out-of-date. This is probably not a big deal with the guestbook.

Note that if you're getting an object by key directly, it will never be out-of-date. It's only for queries that you can see this issue. You can avoid this problem with queries by placing all the entities that need to be consistent in a [single entity group](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths). Note that this limits the rate at which you can write to the entity group.

In answer to your follow-up question, "Guestbook" is the name of the entity.

Comment: Also thanks for trying to answer my questions! I do appreciate it very much. Most of what I just commented on Daniel's answer also applies to your answer. I still would like to translate the queries mentioned in my question to datastore requests that would get the latest data (lets forget if this is necessary in the case of a guestbook or not). --- also you mentioned: "getting an object by key directly" and "You can avoid this problem with queries by placing all the entities that need to be consistent in a single entity group." -> how do you do that, code examples please?